# laravel 5.4 query exception unknow column error

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

i have this ruote.

```
Route::get('/artist/{id}/{slug}', 'HomeController@artist')->name('artist');
```

and this is the moded artist.

```
public function artist($id,$slug){
        $artist = Artist::where('id', $id)->where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $hits = Artist::where('id', $id)->where('slug', $slug)->increment('week_hits');
        return view('front.artist', compact('artist'));
    }
```

whati want is increment week_hits field in my artists table. whenever a specific artist page is visited by the user.

but iam getting this error.

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'week_hits' in 'field list' (SQL: update `artists` set `week_hits` = `week_hits` + 1, `updated_at` = 2017-02-26 16:20:04 where `id` = 1 and `slug` = xasan-aadan-samatar)
```

Comment: Could you please provide your table structure

Comment: Why are you showing PHP code, when the error clearly states: SQL. Does the table of `Artist` model (probably _artists_ ) has a column name _week_hits_ ?

Comment: yeah. this is my artists table structure.  id,name,slug,image,biography,week_hits,week_date,status,created_at,updated_at

Comment: @LukaGovedič thanks bro. i have just checked my table structure. again. there is no field called, week_hits, it is week_htis  . i got the error, thanks bro.

Comment: yeah, typos are the most common and the most annoying errors